# Zend Framework 2 home page

Tags: php, routes, zend-framework2

I'm experimenting with ZF2, and I have the 1st problem, I downloaded Skeleton Application, and uploaded to a shared hosting, Now if I try to access it here http://zend.cojocaruvadim.com/ it doesn't work. If I access it here http://zend.cojocaruvadim.com/index.php/ it works. In control panel I setup subdomain to point to `public_html/zen2/public`.

On localhost if I try `localhost/zend2/public` the same Structure works without any specific configuration, and without domain pointing, because I don't care on local about word public in the url on local.

How to make it work on shared hosting, or should I ask hosting providers for some support?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Problem was from shared hosting, thx for your input!

Comment: Contact your provider ;) Maybe .htaccess is not read or some misconfiguration is happening.

Comment: did you upload your htaccess? possibly your FTP client is ignoring it as a hidden file and hasn't updated it, or your host isn't allowing it.